# Density of smooth function in some weighted Lebesgue space

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $ p : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a continuous function such that $ p(x) \geq 0,\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}. $ I would like to see if the space $ D( \mathbb{R}) = C_c^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}) $ is dense in the weighted Lebesgue space $ L^2(\mathbb{R}, p dx). $ Trying the classical procedure, i.e. smoothing by convolution with some sequence of mollifiers $ (\rho_n)_n $ and later multipliying by a truncature sequence of functions $ \theta_n(x) = \theta(\frac{x}{n}) $ where $ \theta \in D( \mathbb{R}),\ 0 \leq \theta \leq 1,\ \theta(x) = 1,\ \vert x \vert \leq 1 $ and $ \theta(x) = 0,\ \vert x \vert \geq 2. $ But, quickly, we are blocked because of the existence of the weight $ p. $ Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

First, we have
$$
\int_{|x|>n} p f^2 \ dx \to 0 \quad \text{ for } n\to\infty,
$$
for $f\in L^2(p\, dx)$, since $pf^2 \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.
Then we only need to approximate $f$ on some interval $[-n,+n]$.

Second, we can restrict ourselves to bounded functions as
$$
\int_{|x|>n} p \max(-r,\min(f,+r))^2 \ dx \to 
\int_{|x|>n} p f^2 \quad \text{ for } r\to\infty
$$
by dominated convergence. Now, a bounded function is square-integrable on a bounded set.

Third, on the compact interval $p$ is bounded above, and there is $M>0$ such that  $0\le  p(x) \le M$ for all $x\in [-n,+n]$.
This implies
$$
\|f\|_{L^2((-n,+n), p \ dx)}\le \sqrt M \|f\|_{L^2((-n,+n))}
\quad \forall f\in L^2((-n,+n)).
$$
Now one approximates such $f$ on $(-n,+n)$ in the standard $L^2$-norm by a function $\phi \in C_c((-n,n))$. By the inequality above, it is still close to $f$ in the weighted norm.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: While this approach using the local boundedness of $p$ is probably the easiest in the case at hand, let me remark that it is not necessary. In general, if $\mu$ is a Radon measure, then $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ because $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$ using the regularity of $\mu$ and $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb R)$ in the inductive limit topology.

Comment: I don't see why $L^2((-n,n),pdx)\subset L^2((-n,n),dx)$. In fact, the inequality between norms is saying the opposite, isn't it? Let $p(x)=x^2$ in $(0,1)$. Then $f(x)=1/x$ is in $L^2((0,1),pdx)$ but not in $L^2((0,1))$ if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @daw Then I think the argument fails. However, it seems fixable considering $f_R(x)=\max(-R,\min(f(x),R))$ which (for large $R$) is a good approximation of $f$ in $L^2((-n,n),pdx)$. Then, $f_R$ is in $L^2((-n,n))$ and we can follow the argument as you did.

Comment: yes, ofc. thanks again. tried to repair the argument.